# How to test JSF application

Tags: jsf, jboss-arquillian

I would like to test UI part and the state of managed beans as well. 
Previously I used JSFUnit and want to know if something better exists in JSF world.
I heard about Arquillian and read some articles but never used it.

How would you suggest to test?

Comment: [Easy Unit Testing JSF Backing Beans](http://blog.primefaces.org/?p=521)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Arquillian Drone is the next iteration of JSFUnit.  You can read about it here: http://arquillian.org/guides/functional_testing_using_graphene/